# Query with Type not Equal in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

im doing the following query which work perfectly and brings me the part of the documents that complies the type filter

```
db.users.find({phoneNumber:/^\+/, devices:{$exists:true, $type:3}});
```

However im trying to get all the devices that exists but are not type 3 (object), i could go trying each type [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/], but wanted to know if it is possible to negate type 3 i tried

```
db.users.count({phoneNumber:/^\+/, devices:{$exists:true, $type: { $neq: 3}}});
db.users.count({phoneNumber:/^\+/, devices:{$exists:true, $type: { $not: 3}}});
db.users.count({phoneNumber:/^\+/, devices:{$exists:true, $type: { $not: {$eq:3}}}});
```

But all of them throw the same exception

```
exception: type not supported for appendMinElementForType
```

Any clues on how to do this query?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should work as expected :

```
{phoneNumber:/^\+/ ,$and:[{devices:{$exists:true}},{devices:{$not:{$type:3}}}]}
```

This note from the mongodb docs might be of interest to understand what's going on here (copied from [MongoDB reference docs - $and operator manual page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) - emphasis is mine):

> MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions. Using an explicit AND with the **$and operator is necessary when the same field or operator has to be specified in multiple expressions**.

Comment: Is there an explanation to this?

Comment: @MikeMajara sure, it deserved some background. I've edited the answer to point you to the relevant manual page & info, be sure to check it out. ++